What is the name of the inequality $|a+b|^p\le 2^{p-1}(a^p + b^p)$, for positive $a,b$ and $p\ge1$?
I recently ran across the inequality
$$(a+b)^p\le 2^{p-1}(a^p + b^p),$$
valid for positive real $a,b$ and $p\ge1$.
It has an amusing 2 line  proof; it is occasionally very useful.  Does it have a name? You know, like "Bernstein's Other Inequality" or "Minkowski's Lesser
Inequality", or something?
I've looked in Beckenbach and Bellmans' Inequalities book, without luck.

That is the midpoint-convexity for the function $t \mapsto t^p$, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/978687/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/a/700853/42969

@MartinR Thanks.  I used the log convexity of $t\mapsto\cosh t$.

I just realized this is  Hölder's inequality appied to the vectors $(a,b)$ and $(1,1)$ in  $\mathbb R^2$: if $q=p/(p-1)$, then
$$ |(a,b)\cdot(1,1)|\le \|(a,b)\|_p \|(1,1)\|_q,$$
and so
$$ |(a,b)\cdot(1,1)|^p\le \|(a,b)\|_p^p \|(1,1)\|_q^p,$$
where the first factor is $a^p+b^p)$ and the last factor is $2^{p/q}=2^{p-1}$.
